# JQuery/PHP: Replace a select box with another select box on a different page

Tags: php, jquery, select, load, drop-down-menu

On my main page, I have a simple dropdown box:

```
<select name="miles" id="miles">
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="75">75</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="button" id="button">Search</button>
```

When this button is clicked, it performs a JQuery $.load:

```
$("#miles").load("main_data.php #miles_data");
```

And here the page button is calling, main_data.php:

```
<?php

... code to calculate $b

?>

<span id="miles_data">
<option value="5" <?php if ($b == 5) { echo "selected"; } ?>>5</option>
<option value="10" <?php if ($b == 10) { echo "selected"; } ?>>10</option>
<option value="15" <?php if ($b == 15) { echo "selected"; } ?>>15</option>
<option value="25" <?php if ($b == 25) { echo "selected"; } ?>>25</option>
<option value="50" <?php if ($b == 50) { echo "selected"; } ?>>50</option>
<option value="75" <?php if ($b == 75) { echo "selected"; } ?>>75</option>
<option value="100" <?php if ($b == 100) { echo "selected"; } ?>>100</option>
</span>
```

My goals seem simple: Execute a $.load to another page, calculate an integer and set it to a variable, select the matching dropdown item and return it to the main page.

With my code above, the dropdown box on the main page becomes blank. Does anyone notice a solution?

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/ under "Script Execution". Maybe this helps...

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that the format for a selected 'option' is:

```
<select>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Blatantly ripped from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

So you want to have

```
<option value="5" <?php if ($b == 5) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>5</option>
```

Comment: Both `selected="selected"` and `selected` function properly. Thanks though.